# What happens to an await call that hasn't completed before the caller is disposed?

Tags: c#, async-await

Imagine a scenario where you have one form of a control or another. It can be a page on WP8, or a Form in WinForms, I don't think it matters (or does it?). At some point you call await on a method, but shortly after that the control get's closed by the user.

What happens to the task that you were awaiting? Does it continue execution? If it returns, where does it return to? If it cancels, is an exception thrown?

Finally, is there a way to specify you want the execution to continue/complete?

Comment: "The caller" is a method, not an object, so I don't think it makes sense to think of it as that the caller is disposed. (Technically, the method is transformed to a class, but even then, that isn't what gets disposed.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Task` continues execution. It cannot be any other way because running code can only be aborted cooperatively (not considering the evil `Thread.Abort` here).

The `Task` knows nothing about its environment. It is the awaiter which gets notified of completion and tries to resume the async method on the captured `SynchronizationContext`.

It depends entirely on the `SynchronizationContext` what happens. There are many different possible contexts and the full answer depends on your GUI framework.

Comment: That was my reasoning too, I was expecting the execution to continue. However when I try to test it, on WP8, it never returns from a nested await call.

Comment: Nested awaits also post to the captured context, except if you have used `ConfigureAwait(false)`. It seems that WP8 no longer executes callbacks if the sync context is disposed. Then, everything stops and your awaits hang forever.